# Getting correct first frame from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput - AVFoundation

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am capturing video from back camera using AVFoundation and would like to process the frames when I press start button. The problem is that, the moment I press start button, I grab the frame from the sample buffer and process it but it seems that the frame that I get is the past frame, meaning not the current frame that I want.

I understand that sample buffer will come at a delayed timing. I tried using the presentation timestamp of the sample buffer but I don't seem to be able to get it in sync. Has anyone faced a similar problem before? Any help or advice will be appreciated.

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
        didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
        fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

That is where I get my frames.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution for this in case someone else is facing the same problem.

From what I understand, apple does not guarantee that the moment you press the capture button you will get that frame because they are queued in the serial queue buffer that you set. You will definitely get it in sequence but not realtime. In order to ignore the past frames before you press the button, I make use of NSDate to measure the time taken when I start running the capture session (startTime) and the time when the first frame is processed in the capture output delegate (endTime)

So, time taken = endTime-startTime

With this time, we can calculate the frame delay, which in my case, I capture at 24FPS and the frame delay is 3 frames, so when the user press the capture button, I will NOT store/process the first 3 frames so that the result can be in sync with what the user captures.

Hope that helps and feel free to give better suggestions and edit.